# handling null values of datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a Linq query , which consists of this datetime field i'm extracting from database

```
           TerminationDate = base.ConvertFromUtcToCentral(r.TerminationDate.ToString())
```

the function used is designed like this

```
           public DateTime ConvertFromUtcToCentral(string UtcTime)
    {

        if (UtcTime != "")
        {
            DateTime?  retValue = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime
                                                       (UtcTime), USTimeZones.Central);

            return Convert.ToDateTime(retValue);
        }
        else
            return Convert.ToDateTime(null);

    }
```

But whenever i return null it shows up the min date in the grid that i assign this query to. However, when it is null, it should just showup null instead of min date. can you please let me know how i can handle this?Also let me knoww if using ternary operator is a better idea.

Restrictions: Can't change the function retrun type as it is used in several places

Comment: What is passed as string UtcTime if the DateTime is actually NULL?

Comment: empty string "" will be passed if UtcTime is actually null in DB

Comment: What's the type of `r.TerminationDate` anyways, and why do you convert it to a `string` and then from `string` to `DateTime` again?

Comment: As far as i know there isn't a way to make it show up null as the DateTime null value is the same as the Min Value which i believe is January 1st 1900 12:00 AM or something along those lines. Is there a specific reason that you need it to return null instead of min date? If so, where is it necessary to have the null value? In the DB or in your code?

Comment: That a function is used in several places should not keep you from refactoring it if that's the requirement. And in this case it seems the most reasonable way forward.

Comment: I generally agree with @Joanna, but I would also understand them not wanting to change the public interface of a class that may be used in several projects. :D

Comment: @hangy - that's very true and if that's the case then I wouldn't recommend it. It doesn't sound like that's the problem here though. Refactoring is a word that many people fear and for a good reason, especially if the test coverage is not impressive or the code base is just too big to know 'everything'.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are returning a value type, DateTime, you can not return null. You can either change your function to return a nullible DateTime (DateTime?), throw an exception, or return the default value for DateTime, default(DateTime). IMHO I would throw a System.ArgumentException since an empty string to convert is clearly not going to produce a output.

Comment: FYI: `Convert.ToDateTime(null)` does return `DateTime.MinValue` which also happens to be the value of `default(DateTime)`.

Comment: @hangy Oops my bad. Need to read the question a bit more slowly next time.

Comment: :) anyways, throwing an exception would actually change the behaviour of the the method and in some way the public interface of the class. a breaking change like that might cause more problems (user error report) than a `DateTime.MinValue` showing up in some GUI.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try to return `null`.
Make your function for return `DateTime?`, 
so instead of `return Convert.ToDateTime(null);` you can do `return null`

sorry for the bad english!

Comment: the function is used at several places in different queries. So, it would be hard now to modify the function

Comment: +1. @Nishanth, Can you please update your question with restrictions you have - so far changing return type is the only reasonable approach as DateTime value type does not have special "null" value (min value is the closest you can get without nullable types).

Comment: If the function is used in several places why aren't you just calling the function and passing in parameters? The whole point of functions is for code reuse so you should only be changing the function once.

Answer (score 1):

With the restriction that you can't change the function then you could throw a terinery operator in:

```
TerminationDate = ( base.ConvertFromUtcToCentral(r.TerminationDate.ToString()) == default(DateTime) ? (DateTime?) null : (DateTime ?) base.ConvertFromUtcToCentral(r.TerminationDate.ToString()) );
```

I don't like this as it call the function twice. I would probably write a wrapper method that did something like this

```
public static DateTime? WrapperConvertFromUtcToCentral(string UtcTime)
{
    DateTime value = ConvertFromUtcToCentral(string UtcTime);

    if (value == default(DateTime))
         return (DateTime?)null;
    else
         return (DateTime?)value;
}

TerminationDate = WrapperConvertFromUtcToCentral(r.TerminationDate.ToString())
```

This way you are calling the orignal function only once.

Comment: a wrapper was the first thing that came to my mind - I agree that it's as graceful a solution as the conditions allow

Answer (score 1):

The recent edits and comments suggest that `TerminationDate` probably is `DateTime?`. Maybe adding a new overload that explicitly handles `DateTime` and `DateTime` values and correctly returns `DateTime` or `DateTime?` instead? I see that you cannot change the return type of this method easily, so adding those new overloads and gradually using them in your application could be a good approach towards to using a better data type.

```
public DateTime ConvertFromUtcToCentral(string UtcTime)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(UtcTime)
        ? this.ConvertFromUtcToCentral(Convert.ToDateTime(UtcTime))
        : default(DateTime);
}

public DateTime? ConvertFromUtcToCentral(DateTime? UtcTime)
{
    return UtcTime.HasValue
        ? this.ConvertFromUtcToCentral(UtcTime.Value)
        : (DateTime?)null;
}

public DateTime ConvertFromUtcToCentral(DateTime UtcTime)
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UtcTime, USTimeZones.Central);
}
```

If you do not change return type, you will always need get a non-null `DateTime` value from the method, unless - as user957902 proposed - you begin throwing `Exception`s. :) In the the case that you cannot use this, you might also modify the consuming application to treat `DateTime.MinValue` like `null` and do not display anything.

Using the ternary operator or not can be a matter of taste - in simple cases like these, I do like using it (the line breaks in my example are purely to make it easier to read on SO), because it is pretty easy to read and there are only two paths to be taken canyways.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t assign null value to DateTime since it’s not a nullable type
Try assigning DBNull.Value instead of null while posting it back to database